# Using Nuget package 'Microsoft.Xbox.Live.SDK.WinRT.UWP' with CPP

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, xbox-live

I'm struggling with getting the Xbox Live sign-in working for my game. Everything else is ready to go and this is now the final blocker.

Looking at the MSDN documentation page - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/develop-creators-title-with-visual-studio), it looks like it should be trivial. However, I'm not using CX/CPP, merely CPP / winrt and therefore, I'd expect to use ***Microsoft.Xbox.Live.SDK.WinRT.UWP*** rather than ***Microsoft.Xbox.Live.Sdk.UWP***.

In my project, I've added the link, but it's then not clear what I'm meant to do next. I was expecting to then have the C++ headers be created automatically but I can't see anything being built. Does anyone either:

1. Know the equivalent code to use to do sign in in the CPP/WinRT world?
2. Know that it can't be done / I should use a different approach?

Any help gratefully received. Apologies if this is Cpp/winrt 101. I've been using the templates from [MS Blogs / Chuck W](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/) and so everything else has 'just worked' and so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: The NuGet package seems to come with headers already, that you can `#include`. They look to be standard C++ headers, so they should be consumable by any C++ project (vanilla C++, C++/CX, or C++/WinRT).

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable, that was my first thought. I've added the include paths manually (would have expected them to be added automatically), when I do that however, I'm then receiving errors about **::Platform::Guid** not being declared (from vccorlib.h).

It's not clear where that would then be sourced from.

Comment: The final error is:

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\vccorlib.h(356): error C3940: 'Guid': identifier not found - possible mismatch between compiler and library versions. Please ensure vccorlib.h/.lib, vccorlib120.dll and c1xx.dll match

Which makes me think that this Nuget package is incompatible with the settings that the DX templates are using. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in this area so not sure where to look next